# Algebraic manipulation of the derivative definition (Fréchet derivative)

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If we consider a function $f:  \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Starting from the definition of the derivative at point $a$.

$$ f'(a) = \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$$

We can subtract $f'(a)$ on both sides.

$$ 0 = \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h} - f'(a)$$

So far the limit is not being applied to $f'(a)$. I am trying to understand the last two steps, i.e.,

$$ 0 = \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h} - \frac{hf'(a)}{h} $$

Here $f'(a)$ is being multiplied and divided by $h$, but $h$ is under a limit.

$$ 0 = \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)-f'(a)h}{h}$$

Which explicit limit rule allows us to manipulate the above two expressions like an ordinary algebraic expression and apply the limit on the entire expression? A similar expression is employed in the definition of Fréchet derivative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, for the equiation
$$0 = \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h} - f'(a),$$ you can use that $f'(a)$ is constante (because its evaluated in $a$) so $\lim_{h \to 0} f'(a)=f'(a)$, then:
$$ \lim\limits_{h \to 0}\left( \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h} \right) - f'(a) = \lim\limits_{h \to 0}\left( \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h} \right) - \lim_{h \to 0} f'(a) = \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \left( \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h} - f'(a) \right).$$

Here the rule used is the lineality of the limit, i.e. $\lim_{h \to 0} f(h) + \lim_{h \to 0} g(h) = \lim_{h \to 0} ( f(h)+g(h))$.

Finnaly in the equiation
$$\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h} - \frac{hf'(a)}{h}= \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)-f'(a)h}{h},$$
arises from common denominator of fractions.

Comment: Thank you, so once $f'(a)$ is under the limit, we can treat the whole internal expression algebraically, i.e., we can can now divide and multiply $f'(a)$ by $h$? Is this correct?

Comment: @AChem: Yes, once al the terms are under the limit, begin purely algebraically manipulation.