# Unsure of a definition of the Frechet Derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

This might be weird, but I found this formula of the Frechet derivative in class notes I'm using, and I'm not sure it is correct because I cannot find any information about it on vector functions (I can find a similar notation equivalent for scalar functions for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4630418/algebraic-manipulation-of-the-derivative-definition-fr%C3%A9chet-derivative)).

With $f^*: \mathbb{R}^n \xrightarrow{} \mathbb{R}$,

$$
\underset{\|x - y\|_1 \rightarrow 0}{\lim} \frac{f(x) - f(y) - \langle \nabla f(y), x-y\rangle}{\|x - y\|_1} = 0\\
$$

Is it correct ? If it is, how did they obtain this result ? I couldn't find any posts about it.

Comment: Look for the standard definition of differentiability of a function $\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^m$. If you really can't find it any number of places, go to minute 34 of [my YouTube lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VG3J1MdhebA&list=PL5I-Eyk8l9FHdJUd9UujGcvumjCFPHbrd&index=22&t=1215s).

Comment: If you replace $x$ by $y + h$, and remember that $\nabla f(y)$ is the unique vector $v$ such that $\forall h,\,Df(y)(h) = \langle v, h\rangle$, what do you get?

Comment: P.S. Why the asterisk on $f$?

Comment: When will teachers/professors stop needlessly introducing inner products to multivariable calculus?

Comment: @FranzFerdX This is nearly the definition, where $f(x)-f(y)$ in the numerator gets subtracted a linear function $A:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ of the increment $x-y$. So, $f(x)-f(y)-A(x-y)$. Being the co-domain of this linear function of dimension $1$, then it can be represented as an inner product (properly and not needlessly used in the formula) by some unique vector. That vector is the definition of $\nabla f(y)$.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins When they don't know what they are doing, they will stop.

Comment: @NDB I take umbrage with the use of $\nabla f$ here only because the identification of a linear function $A : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ with a vector is not canonical and introduces unnecessary additional structure. The definition of $\nabla f$ is the vector such that $df = \langle \nabla f , \cdot\rangle$. Why not just use $df$? You take a natural 1-form $df$ and turn it into a vector $\nabla f$ only to use it in a (non-canonical) inner product, effectively turning it back into a 1-form.

Comment: And I think it's a genuine problem because using the inner product here might hinder OP in understanding the generalization of the derivative to maps $f : V \to W$ where $V, W$ are, say, banach spaces where we don't have an inner product sitting around.

Comment: Personally I prefer the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition, there exists some continuous $L$ such that for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists some $\delta>0$ such that  $|f(x+h)-f(x)- Lh | \le \epsilon \|h\|$ for all $\|h\| < \delta$. No fiddly limits, little o silliness, etc.